# MPPI controller in ackermann gives low cmd_vel while aligning to goal angle

Tags: ros2, nav2

I'm currently using mppi controller nav2 in a ackermann FWD robot,I observed that while the controller is near the goal and needs to align to the goal angle it gives very low linear velocity with which won't be accepted by my motor controller **(0.05 m/s is the velocity to move the robot / the velocity where rpm can be send to the motor)** but mppi gives so low as **0.01 and 0.02 m/s** in linear velocity. Is there any  crtitics that need to be tuned or can someone give me any suggestions for tuning  MPPI on ackermann

Distro: Humble
MPPI ver: 1.1.8 (binary install)

Comment: What ROS distribution are you using and version of MPPI?

Comment: Distro: Humble, MPPI ver: 1.1.8 (binary install)